# Equivalent of keyset in perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash declared like this:

```
$test = {
    "A" => "B",
    "C" => "D",
    "E" => "F",
};
```

I would like to get the keys ["A", "C", "E"] in an array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
keys %{$test}
```

(see: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)

Comment: N.B.: _Starting with Perl 5.14, keys can take a scalar EXPR, which must contain a reference to an unblessed hash or array. The argument will be dereferenced automatically._, i.e. `use 5.14.0; ... keys $test`

Comment: Good point Joel. Although my understanding was that `keys HASHREF` was an experimental addition to 5.14 that might end up being changed/removed in the future?

Comment: I should have posted the next sentence from [`perldoc -f keys`](http://p3rl.org/keys): _This aspect of keys is considered highly experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of Perl._ But I think people like the concept and `keys $ref` had no previous meaning, therefore this is one of those rare language additions that _should_ have no backwards incompatibilities; the only code it could break never ran in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for adding that Joel (thought I'd seen the comment about it being experimental recently - turns out it was in the perl docs I'd linked to :-) ).

Answer (score 4):

Well, `$test` is a hash reference, so just de-reference it and assign the keys to an array:

```
my @array=keys %$test;
```

Answer (score 0):

`keys` is what you need. See here:

http://perl.about.com/od/programmingperl/qt/perlkeys.htm

Comment: Or the more official [`perldoc -f keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html)